# Entity Framework AsNoTracking on table is faster than directly calling stored procedure through EF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a situation where if I have a DbSet linked to a table by EF and I query it using LINQ, it is consistently slower than directly using a stored procedure that has been linked up to the stored procedure in the database using the generate model feature of EF.

How could this be?

This is the code for querying the table with EF with AsNoTracking():

```
var relatedParcels = _db.Parcels
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(parcel => parcel.Flag == false)
                .Where(parcel => parcel.Id != givenThing.id)
                .Where(parcel => parcel.Geometry != null).ToArray()
                .Where(parcel => parcel.Geometry.Intersects(bufferedGeometry))
                .Where(parcel => parcel.Forecasts.Any(forecast => forecast.Year == finalYear
                                                          && (forecast.Area1Id == mainArea
                                                              || forecast.Area2Id == mainArea)))
                .ToArray();

return relatedParcels .Select(relatedParcel => relatedParcel.Forecasts
                .Where(forecast => forecasts.Year == previousYear)
                .ToArray());
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
SELECT Forecasts.*
FROM Forecasts
WHERE Forecasts.Year = @PreviousYear 
  AND Forecasts.ParcelId IN (SELECT Parcel.Id
                             FROM Parcel
                             INNER JOIN Geometry ON Parcel.GeometryId = Geometry .Id
                             WHERE Parcel.Flag = 0 
                               AND Parcel.Id != @ParcelId
                               AND Geometry.CentroidPoint.STIntersects(@NearbyGeometry.STBuffer(@Buffer)) = 1 
                               AND Parcel.Id IN (SELECT Forecasts.ParcelId
                                                 FROM Forecasts
                                                 WHERE Forecasts.Year = @FinalYear 
                                                   AND (Forecasts.Area1Id = @MainArea 
                                                        OR Forecasts.Area2Id = @MainArea)
```

And this is how it is called:

```
var relatedParcels = db.RelatedParcels(parcelId, buffer, geometry, finalYear, mainArea, previousYear).GroupBy(x => x.parcelId);
```

The LINQ query directly to the table is consistently 3 times faster than directly calling the stored procedure.

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and EF 6.

TLDR: how could EF ever be faster than a stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried to call SP without `GroupBy` like `db.RelatedParcels(parcelId, buffer, geometry, finalYear, mainArea, previousYear);` ? Does this chages anything?

Comment: There is no need to discuss which is faster and why until you have tested in a way that makes sense, and that is consistent comparing like with like

Comment: This is not an EF question, it is a difference between the query EF generates and your comparison stored procedure. To gain an explanation for the difference, look at the execution plans for the query vs. the stored procedure.  AsNoTracking() doesn't make a query run faster, it just avoids the extra time the EF DbContext needs to resolve and load entities into it's cache.